# basic sql : selecting AVG() values from the same column multiple times in one query, when each wanted AVG() value uses different WHERE clause

Tags: sql, average, multiple-conditions

I want to get three different average values from one column (value_to_count) inside one table where all of those average values has a different WHERE clause (according to time).

#### Example Data:

```
###services#### Table
service_id       value_to_count                time
-----------      -----------------------       ---------
     604                    2054               04:04:50
     604                    3444               05:00:15
     604                    2122               07:12:50
     604                    2144               09:10:50
     604                    2001               13:12:53
     602                    2011               15:00:12
     602                    2115               17:22:35
     602                    1411               20:22:12
     602                    1611               21:04:52
     602                    2111               23:43:45
```

I'm using this query at the moment to get the average value on time between 18 and 23:

#### Query

```
SELECT 
service_id AS service, AVG(value_to_count) AS primetime 
FROM services 
WHERE HOUR(time) BETWEEN 18 AND 23 
GROUP BY service_id
```

And it gives me this kind of results:

```
### Result #### 
service          primetime
-----------      --------------      
     604               2154           
     602               2444
```

Now I want to get other average values next to the one I already got. This time I just want to get averages by 'HOUR(time) BETWEEN 06 AND 18' and 'HOUR(time) BETWEEN 23 AND 06' aswell.

This is the form of result I want to get:

```
### Wanted Result #### 
service          primetime          other_time_interval_1   other_time_interval_2
-----------      --------------     ----------------        ------------------
     604               2154              2352                      1842
     602               2444              4122                      1224
```

Comment: `BETWEEN 23 and 06` is not going to work. It has to be split into two separate conditions. Also, you seem to be double counting the events in the hours 18, 23 and 06, since both limits are inclusive.

Answer (score 9):

This should do it:

```
SELECT service_id AS service, 
       AVG(case when HOUR(time) BETWEEN 18 AND 23 then value_to_count else null end) AS primetime,
       AVG(case when HOUR(time) BETWEEN 06 AND 18 then value_to_count else null end) AS other_time_interval_1
FROM services 
GROUP BY service_id
```

Comment: That did the work for getting three different results like I had in mind. Thanks alot for that. Now I noticed that my 'HOUR(time) BETWEEN 23 AND 06' is giving me NULL because it can't compare the hour just like that. I tried to add two conditions inside one 'case when' clause separated with AND or a comma, but I just got NULL or errors again. Any way to compare time from 23 to 24 and then 00 to 06 inside the same 'case when'?

Comment: As pointed out to OP, `BETWEEN 23 and 06` is not going to work. It has to be split into two separate conditions

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: ah, right (copy & paste without thinking...)

Answer (score 4):

I'd first define the periods for each piece of data, then worry about grouping and averaging:

```
;With ServicePeriods as (
    SELECT Service_id,value_to_count,
       CASE WHEN HOUR(time) between 18 and 22 THEN 1
            WHEN HOUR(time) between 06 and 17 THEN 2
            ELSE 3 END as period
    FROM Services
)
select Service_Id,
    AVG(CASE WHEN period=1 THEN value_to_count END) as prime_time,
    AVG(CASE WHEN period=2 THEN value_to_count END) as other_time_interval_1,
    AVG(CASE WHEN period=3 THEN value_to_count END) as other_time_interval_2
from
    ServicePeriods
group by Service_id
```

(Actually, at first I did it as outputting as 3 separate rows, but now I've pivoted as per your requested results)

Because my first `CASE` covers all periods, I don't need to think about "between 23 and 06". Note that I've also adjusted the ranges to avoid double counting.

If you want to explicitly check for `HOUR(time) between 23 and 06` (or 05), you can do `HOUR(time) >= 23 or HOUR(time) <= 6` (or `<`). Note that you want `OR`, not `AND`

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Widened my gaze a lot.