# Multiple AVG in single SQL query

Tags: sql, average, multiple-conditions

I've searched for adding multiple AVG calculations and have found a few entries, however I'm having to join another table and the examples of that are scarce.

closest answer I can find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462873/basic-sql-selecting-avg-values-from-the-same-column-multiple-times-in-one-qu)
but it deals with dates and no joins

here are my tables:

indicators:

```
StandardScore             IndicatorID      NID    DID
0.033333                  7                1      1
0.907723                  9                1      1
0.574739                  26               1      1
0.917391                  21               1      1
.....
```

indexindicators:

```
IndexID                   IndicatorID
1                         7
1                         26
2                         21
3                         7
4                         9
4                         21
4                         7
5                         9
.......
```

My goal is to get the average for each IndexID (indexindicators) related to NID/DID (indicators) combination

a query to retrieve a single value would be

```
SELECT AVG(StandardScore) FROM `indicators` INNER JOIN indexindicators ON indicators.IndicatorId=indexindicators.IndicatorId WHERE nid=1 AND did=1 AND indexindicators.IndexId=1
```

ultimately there will be 6 (indexID) averages which then have to be rounded then * by 100 (should I do that part with PHP?)

This seems like such a simple query, but i just can't seem wrap my mind around it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: is indexindicators.IndexId have to be same value with nid and did?

Comment: no. indexid will range from 1-6 , nid from 1-40 and did 1-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT nid, did, indexid, 100.0 * AVG(StandardScore) 
    FROM 'indicators'
    INNER JOIN 'indexindicators'
      ON indicators.IndicatorId=indexindicators.IndicatorId 
group by nid, did, indexid
```

Comment: Thanks so much! worked like a charm (MyPHPAdmin didn't like the ' though but it worked out.